# How to find whether words are noun,verb, or adjectives (parts of speech) in a google spreadsheet

Tags: html

Hi I'm trying to use Google Sheets to Import a dictionary website and have it output whether a list of words I have is an adjective, verb, noun etc.

I have thousands of words to do this for which is why I'm trying to automate it.

I found some formulas online that use googlesheets Importhtml function and then take the xpath to get the verbs,adjectives,nouns

I think that those websites have changed however and now I have been unsuccessful trying to find the xpath on any dictionary site.

here is a link to my google doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16G882tK8rnU7S22PwSk8BoTXm3EWHOJpH7177Bs39eo/edit?usp=sharing

If anyone is able to find an xpath for a dictionary that will be able to output verbs adjectives and nouns that would be amazing

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Is this some kind of homework? Because if you want to professionally detect something like that I would use a programming language like Python to export a csv with your solution. Its kinda ambitious to properly do it in excel but it depends on your context. If you go for a programming language then you could check out corenlp(https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) and (https://www.nltk.org/book). Looking at your technical problem I would first check what importxml actually does and what the servers of your websites respond. Normally they shouldnt respond with their

Comment: whole dictionary as that would slow them down and the website would not load properly. In that case you need to check their apis for the right request to get what you need. Normally there is pagination involved and I doupt that this is possible or easy to handle in spreadsheet.

Comment: Looking deeper into your spreadsheet it appears that you have these quotes: “ instead of these ". Spreadsheet then tells you that it cannot parse the formula. When using these quotes (") it says that it cannot parse the results.

Comment: Hi @telion this is for a research project. We have large amounts of audio that we transcribe using google and then edit manually. However we also do some entirely manually and we want to be able to timestamp words that are nouns, verbs and adjectives since they are informative for the research we are doing. I don't actually know much at all about coding which is why I was trying to do it on google sheets.

Comment: This website: https://caninfotech.com/office-suites/find-noun-verb-adjective-google-spreadsheet/ seemed to have at some point a working Importhtml formula. I'm just not sure how they were able to find the x-path (or at least that's what I think it is) for the formiula.

Comment: I also watched a few videos on how to find the x-path, or rather extract what it is you want to import from the website, and it seems people are able to do it with the Importhtml function on google sheets. I think I just lack html ability to figure out exactly what I need to write in the excel formula to constrain the import to only tell me what type of word it is.

Answer (score 2):

### Please, please don't do this.

Identifying parts of speech in task is *not* a trivial task.  (See [the Wikipedia entry on part-of-speech tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) for an overview of what's involved.)  Looking up words in a dictionary is an extremely crude way to do this for English, where a single orthographic "word" can represent different parts of speech depending on context.

And for your dataset, [the method described on CanInfoTech](https://caninfotech.com/office-suites/find-noun-verb-adjective-google-spreadsheet/) is woefully inadequate.  Here's an illustration of how those three online dictionaries will tag the first few entries in your spreadsheet:

```
Word    dictionary.com    Merriam-Webster   lexico.com
a       noun              noun              determiner
woman   noun              noun              noun
and     conjunction       conjunction       conjunction
two     noun              adjective         cardinal number
kids    noun              noun              noun
a       noun              noun              determiner
girl    noun              noun              noun
and     conjunction       conjunction       conjunction
a       noun              noun              determiner
boy     noun              noun              noun
the     definite article  definite article  determiner
boy     noun              noun              noun
is      verb              abbreviation      abbreviation
trying  adjective         adjective         adjective
to      preposition       preposition       preposition
reach   verb              verb              verb
the     definite article  definite article  determiner
cookie  noun              noun              noun
jar     noun              noun              noun
```

As you can see, many problems are obvious already:

1. The determiner "a" is incorrectly tagged as a noun by dictionary.com and Merriam-Webster, because those two sources happen to list the noun form (i.e., the name of the letter "A") first.  Since "a" is so common, this will give you an enormous false positive rate for nouns.
2. Similarly, "is" is incorrectly tagged as an abbreviation by Merriam-Webster and lexico.com, because the "IS" abbreviation happens to be listed first on those sites.  This will give you many false negatives for verbs.
3. "trying" is incorrectly tagged as an adjective by all three sources.  Of course, "trying" is also an adjective, but in this context it is a form of the verb "try", and you would want it to be tagged as such.  (I assume you're not limiting your search to finite verbs.)

No automated POS-tagging system is perfect, but this one is so abysmally bad that it will render your research results worthless.

### Use a real POS-tagger instead.

As @telion points out, there are plenty of free resources out there that do pretty good POS-tagging on text.  R and Python have plenty of options.  You won't be able to do this in Google Sheets, but a programming language will give you far more flexibility for your quantitative analysis anyway.

### @telion's comment solves your problem.

Replace the quote characters (both single and double), as @telion describes.  Also, as you suspected, dictionary.com has indeed changed; you can inspect a sample definition page to determine the new correct class to use in its formula.  Finally, you'll need to remove the final periods from words at the ends of sentences.

Comment: Thank you everyone who has posted responses! This has definitely helped me doge a bullet as well as lots of time!